# Calling a field in views-view-fields--view-name.tpl.php ---- Error

Tags: 7, views, theming, debugging

I am trying to call a field by using the line of code:

```
<?php print $field->handler->view->field['title_1']; ?>
```

But i keep getting this error:

[image]

I used devel dpm() to look for what was the correct path to call it and it said `handler->view->field['title_1']`. I am absolutely stumped and I am not sure if I am using the right .tpl.php file or what. Anyone have any ideas?

**---EDIT---**

```
<?php foreach ($fields as $id => $field): ?>
  <?php if (!empty($field->separator)): ?>
  <?php print $field->separator; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php print $field->wrapper_prefix; ?>
<?php print $field->label_html; ?>
<?php print $field->content; ?>
<div>
    <?php print $field->handler->view->field['title_1']; ?>
</div>
<?php print $field->wrapper_suffix; ?>
```

Comment: I've found the best way to look at Drupal objects/arrays is to:
echo '<pre>';
print_r($field->handler);
echo '</pre>';

are you sure $field->handler contains "view" etc?  the error says you're trying to convert an object to a string, but it can't do it.

Comment: You most probably are looking for `$field->content` here; have you looked at and read the comments in the top of the default `views-view-fields.tpl.php` template?

Comment: @jdu - when i do `handler->view->field` it displays as `array` so i am assuming that there is does contain a `view`. that is without the `<pre>` tags around it. how would i go about converting that object to a string?

Comment: @Jimajamma - i have looked into using `$field->content`, but that does not have what I want to display in it. that is the whole display of `<span class="field-content"><a href="/sandbox/node/6" data-thmr="thmr_11 thmr_12">Event Sample 2</a></span>`. what i would like to do is grab specific fields. even ones that are not set to display normally.

Comment: @scapegoat17  dig a bit deeper in to that object..  print_r($field->handler->view) ... eventually you will find the actual value you want to display.  you can either display the raw value,  or do some research to find a drupal function, like render()

Comment: if you are looking for a different field, you should be looking in the `$fields` (plural) variable; but, if it's been set to not display, then you could look in either the `$row` or `$view->result` variables.

Comment: @jdu - I completely agree. I dig deeper into `handler->view->field['title_1']` and then i get an error...

Comment: use `print_r($field->handler->view->field['title_1']);` instead and it will show you what you have to work with.  wrap it with `<pre></pre>` tags if it's messy :)

Comment: @Jimajamma - `$field` is the "each" portion of the foreach on `$fields`. If you look at my edit you will see the full code in the .tpl.php file to work with. i tried wrapping a `print_r` around it and it displayed everything but my view...

Comment: @scapegoat17  I think you're jumping ahead..  the point of looking at it using print_r(); is to show you how it's formed.

find out what is inside:  print_r($field->handler->view->field);    ... then go one level deeper, etc.  do it step by step.

Comment: @jdu - when i try to do a `print_r($field->handler->view->field);` it returns nothing in the content..

Comment: then that is your problem, I think.  could you update your question to include the contents of <pre>print_r($field->handler->view)</pre>  ?   Or use pastebin.com  ?

Answer (score 2):

From the commentary, some points are being missed, but this template is used to create the "row" of fields from a View.

Let's create a simple one:

[image]

which has three fields, a title, a new field and a custom field, which when run looks likes this:

[image]

Now, let's create a `views-view-fields--for-da.tpl.php`, rescan for templates, and add some debugging information to the top of it:

```
drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r(array_keys($fields), TRUE) . '</pre>');
```

and running it again, this will give us:

[image]

So, now, anyplace we want inside this template, we have access to the individual field's content as:

```
$fields['title']->content
$fields['field_new_field']->content
$fields['field_my_custom_field']->content
```

so throwing them in similar `drupal_set_message()`s produces:

[image]

But now, let's say you are exluding one of these fields from display, eg:

[image]

then you will get this:

[image]

but some more digging into `$row` via:

```
drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($row->field_field_my_custom_field, TRUE) . '</pre>');
```

will give you this:

[image]

or access to the content of the excluded field via:

```
$row->field_field_my_custom_field[0]['rendered']['#markup']
```

Obviously, the field names are different here than in your specific example, but I hope you can follow the logic.

Also, if you don't want to dig into `$row` you could always include the field in the display via the Views UI and then exclude it in this template, eg, something like this:

```
<?php foreach ($fields as $id => $field): ?>
  <?php if ($id != 'field_my_custom_field'): ?>
    <?php if (!empty($field->separator)): ?>
      <?php print $field->separator; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php print $field->wrapper_prefix; ?>
      <?php print $field->label_html; ?>
      <?php print $field->content; ?>
      <div class="insert-custom-field-content-here">
        <?php print $fields['field_my_custom_field']->content; ?>
      </div>
    <?php print $field->wrapper_suffix; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

which would print all the fields with the exception of the custom one, but would then include its content after the content of each of the other fields.

Comment: That is an amazing write up, but i still have some questions about `$row->field_field_my_custom_field[0]['rendered']['#markup']`...  the `[0]` portion - wat is being accomplished there? also the same thing for `['#markup']`? Again i am sorry to do this, i am just trying to understand better

Comment: the `[0]` is the delta, it'll be `0` for single value fields, but will be any number of values if you have a multiple value field.

Comment: the `#markup` is the rendered html output of the field.

Comment: if you have only one field excluded from the View, it may be easier to understand if you exclude it via the template, see my addition to the answer.

Comment: So you are saying that in your new edit, that if i want to add another field with a tag around it the way to do it would be to set it to display, and then in the template, set it up how you have it. And by doing that, it will take it out of field content and put it in the div tags that wrap it? Also you wrote `<?php print $fields['field_my_custom_field']->content; ?>` did you mean `$field` instead of `$fields`?

Comment: Yes, if you don't exclude any fields via the Views UI, each one will be present inside `$fields` and in the `foreach()` loop, we check if we are looking at the one we don't want to print via `$id` and then we print it after the field we are currently looking at, so yes, I do mean $fields['...']

Comment: okay, and where did you find the `[field_my_custom_field]` name from? like is it the `machine_name`? or did you find it by looking it up by inspecting the element?

Comment: if you go back up to the beginning, it is the array key of the $fields, each of which point to the individual fields in your View.  Eg, title points to the title field, field_my_custom_field points to the fact that I've included that field in my View.

Comment: I am going to have to use multiple fields. So i guess i am going to have to use `$rows`??]

Comment: you can use either method, switch/case or rows or however you are most comfortable with your php skills.