# How to call image on views tpl file?

Tags: views

I have a view in drupal 7 and I have created a template of this view. Now I need to call image here.

Comment: Is the image the result of view that you created?

Comment: I am using <img src="<?php print image_style_url('home_recent_properties', $fields['field_real_thumbnail']->content); ?>" class="attachment-property-thumb" alt="" /> but its getting me nothing

Comment: What is the output of print_r($fields['field_real_thumbnail']->content); ?

Comment: public:///20141030221735601699000000-1432878640-1

Comment: I am using this here 
views-view-fields--dev-home-recent-properties--block.tpl.php
view tpl file

Comment: please answer.. if you know

Comment: What is `image_style_url('home_recent_properties',`  ? is it suppose to be a string? then you need to add quotation marks around it.

Comment: also I don't see any .png .jpg .gif or anything like that on your `<img src="">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="attachment-property-thumb">
  <?php print $fields["field_real_thumbnail"]->content; ?>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: public:///20141030221735601699000000-1432878640-1 getting this line after using this code.

Comment: On your view, when you configured the real thumbnail field, did you set the formatter to image?

Comment: Great Thanks.. I have one other issue. here I am getting more then 1 image..But I need to use only one image..

Comment: You want a specific image? or does it need to depend on something else like a user or a node?

Comment: my images is comming from MLS listing.. And its giving me 10-11 images. And here I need only one image. not need any specific image.

Comment: set the view's pager to 1? will that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do field level theming.

1. Create a template file having name like: `views-view-fields--your-view-name.tpl.php`
2. `drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r(array_keys($fields), TRUE) . '</pre>');`

see [Calling a field in views-view-fields--view-name.tpl.php ---- Error](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/102647/calling-a-field-in-views-view-fields-view-name-tpl-php-error)

Comment: this code display me 
Array
(
    [0] => field_res_remarks
    [1] => field_res_price
    [2] => field_res_combined_sqft
    [3] => field_res_total_baths
    [4] => field_res_bedrooms
    [5] => field_res_property_sub_type
    [6] => field_res_status
    [7] => field_geo_lat
    [8] => field_geo_lon
    [9] => id
    [10] => field_res_images
    [11] => field_res_listing_id
    [12] => field_res_street_name
    [13] => field_res_city
    [14] => field_res_mls
)

Comment: Plz go through the above mentioned URL.

Comment: I am able to fetch other variable value ..Only image giving me issue.

Comment: Please help . If you have any solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple images, please make changes from view to display only single image as shown in attached file.

Please use below code snippet in your view tpl file.

```
$fid = file_id_from_your_view

$file = file_load($fid);

$img_url = $file->uri;

// Path for your image with specific style
$style_image = image_style_url('your_image_style_to_display', $img_url);
```

Hope this helps you!

Thanks![image]