# Printing an Entity Reference Field Value in a field collection in views-view-fields.tpl.php

Tags: 7, views, theming, entities

I am overriding my view with the template **views-view-fields.tpl.php**, and have called it **views-view-fields--front-featured-blocks.tpl.php**

I wont bother putting all of my code for this block up, but the two defining lines of my code are as follows...

```
<span class="block-entity-id">
  <?php print $fields['field_link_to_content']->content; ?>
</span>

<span class="block-title">
  <?php print $fields['field_block_title']->content; ?>
</span>
```

The *field_block_title* span prints a value, but the *field_link_to_content* does not.

The **field_link_to_content** is an Entity Reference field, which is printing the Entity ID, which I need to build a link.

Can anyone tell me why this doesnt work, but I can print every other field in the same method? The entity reference field is only allowed one value, but is there a delta value involved? How would I print a list of allowed values? I have devel installed.

Comment: what does devel show? can u take a screen shot & upload it

Comment: @NoSssweat How do I print from Devel in a views theme template file? Where would I see the output?

Answer (score 2):

I found my main answer from this question here.. [Calling a field in views-view-fields--view-name.tpl.php ---- Error](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/102647/calling-a-field-in-views-view-fields-view-name-tpl-php-error)

My problem was excluding the display of the field. I assumed that I would want the field hidden as I wanted to show it elsewhere, but as I am overriding the views.view.fields.tpl.php anyway, I could choose to declare it or not.

As soon as I set the field to display again, I could use...

```
print $fields['field_link_to_content']->content;
```

If I had wanted to keep the field hidden, I could have used something like...

```
$row->field_field_my_custom_field[0]['rendered']['#markup']
```

Comment: oh yeah, I had that happen to me, forgot about that.